# Enable cors in nuxt express middleware

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt application with express middleware located in src/api/*

and i want to enable cors for this middleware so that another front end application ( on different domain ) can send requests to it

for some reason the code below is not working as expected

Also interesting is that requests to `localhost:8000/api/*` using postman return HTML instead of the json data I return from my express middlewares.

However if i comment this line of code `app.use(cors());` (remove cors usage) everything starts to work as expected.

Here is my code

src/api/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const config = require('./config');
const syntaxErrorHandler = require('./middlewares/syntaxError')
const api = require('./routes/api');

mongoose.connect(config.database, {
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + config.database)
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err)
});

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(syntaxErrorHandler);

app.use(api);

// export the server middleware
module.exports = {
  path: '/api',
  handler: app
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
const pkg = require('./package')

module.exports = {
  server: {
    port: 8000
  },
  mode: 'universal',

  serverMiddleware: [
    '~/api/index.js'
  ],

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      ...
    ],
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#009def' },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '@/assets/stylus/main.styl',
  ],

  plugins: [
    ...
  ],

  router: {},

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
     ...
  ],


  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
  }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can share a solution if you solved this problem? I face same issue.

Comment: did you ever get a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck with the cors npm package either, so I used plain headers like this to allow requests from ALL sites:

```
const app = express()

// allow all CORS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next()
})
```

One advantage of this light solution is that you don't need to add another package.